# Checkbox values in prestashop

Tags: checkbox, prestashop-1.6

I'm working with prestashop and try to get value from a form with checkbox using a HelperForm

SO what I had is :

```
$fields_form[0]['form']= [
        'legend'=> [
            'title'=> $this->l('Indexation')
        ] ,
        'input'=>[
            [
                'type'=>'text',
                'label'=> $this->l('Base(s) à indexer'),
                'name'=>'options',
                'size'=>20,
                'required'=>true
            ]
        ],
        'submit'=>[
            'title' => $this->l('Save'),
            'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right'
        ]
    ];
```

and then

```
$helper = new HelperForm();
[...]
$helper->toolbar_btn = array(
        'save' =>
            array(
                'desc' => $this->l('Save'),
                'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name.'&save'.$this->name.
                    '&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
            ),
        'back' => array(
            'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
            'desc' => $this->l('Back to list')
        )
    );

    // Load current value
    $helper->fields_value['options'] = Configuration::get('options');

    return $helper->generateForm($fields_form);
```

and in my `getContent` I had :

```
$my_module_name = strval(Tools::getValue('options'));
return $my_module_name;
```

So until there I had no problem. I write 'test' in the text input and then 'test' is returned but I don't want a text input I want a checkbox input so I changed my form for :

```
 $fields_form[0]['form']= [
        'legend'=> [
            'title'=> $this->l('Indexation')
        ] ,
        'input'=>[
            [
                'type'=>'checkbox',
                'label'=> $this->l('Base(s) à indexer'),
                'name'=>'options',
                'required'=>true,
                'values'=>[
                    'query'=>$options,
                    'id'=>'id',
                    'name'=>'name'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'submit'=>[
            'title' => $this->l('Save'),
            'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right'
        ]
    ];
```

and $options is :

```
$options = [
        [
            'id'=>1,
            'name'=>'test'
        ],
        [
            'id'=>2,
            'name'=>'test2'
        ]
    ];
```

and in my `getContent()`: `return (Tools::getValue('options'));`
But with that, nothing is displayed.

Also, if I do `return sizeof(Tools::getValue('options))` It give me 1 no matter what I check with the checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set the name of the field with []

```
$fields_form[0]['form']= [
    'legend'=> [
        'title'=> $this->l('Indexation')
    ] ,
    'input'=>[
        [
            'type'=>'checkbox',
            'label'=> $this->l('Base(s) à indexer'),
            'name'=>'options[]',
            'required'=>true,
            'values'=>[
                'query'=>$options,
                'id'=>'id',
                'name'=>'name'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'submit'=>[
        'title' => $this->l('Save'),
        'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right'
    ]
];
```

Then, you options should have a value:

```
$options = [
    [
        'id'=>1,
        'name'=>'test',
        'val' => 1
    ],
    [
        'id'=>2,
        'name'=>'test2',
        'val' => 2
    ]
];
```

Then you can get the checked values with:

```
Tools::getValue('options')
```

Edit:
In 1.6 we have the admin tpl for the helper:

```
{foreach $input.values.query as $value}
    {assign var=id_checkbox value=$input.name|cat:'_'|cat:$value[$input.values.id]}
    <div class="checkbox{if isset($input.expand) && strtolower($input.expand.default) == 'show'} hidden{/if}">
        {strip}
            <label for="{$id_checkbox}">
                <input type="checkbox" name="{$id_checkbox}" id="{$id_checkbox}" class="{if isset($input.class)}{$input.class}{/if}"{if isset($value.val)} value="{$value.val|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"{/if}{if isset($fields_value[$id_checkbox]) && $fields_value[$id_checkbox]} checked="checked"{/if} />
                {$value[$input.values.name]}
            </label>
        {/strip}
    </div>
{/foreach}
```

So, to set the checkbox value to be returned we need to pass the val:

```
{if isset($value.val)} value="{$value.val|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"{/if}
```

Also, to be checked or not when loading the page we pass the values to meet the criteria:

```
{if isset($fields_value[$id_checkbox]) && $fields_value[$id_checkbox]} checked="checked"{/if}
```

Comment: You saved me. If i can ask you one more things. But I stil have a problem. Let's say I have 5 options. If i check 2 of the five options it just give me an array with ['on','on']. And no matter if i check the first, the second, the third... options I have no way to know wich one is checked.

Comment: that's why you might need to set different values or (val) for each option. you should receive an array with the values selected. in the above example, if you checked both, you receive [1, 2]

Comment: It didn't work but that's because it's val and not value. Thanks for the help, you da the real MVP

Comment: I've edited the information, and added how to get the value checked when opening the page.